# How can I stop jquery from appending json response values to my query string automatically?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, plotly

I'm making an asynchronous put request to an asp.net mvc controller that returns a Json response. Why is jquery automatically appending the returned json fields to my query string and how can i stop it?

Here is the ajax call in the page:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "put",
        async: true,
        url: '/Analysis/TippingPointChartUpdate',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function (result, status, xhr) {
        console.log("action success");

        Plotly.newPlot('plotlyChart', result.PlotlyJSON.x.data, result.PlotlyJSON.x.layout, { scrollZoom: true });

        $("#submitSpinner").hide();

    });
```

Here is the anonymous type I return via a Json response in the asp.net controller:

```
var chartResults = new ChartResultsViewModel
        {
            Id = analysis.Id,
            ChartWidth = model.ChartWidth,
            ChartHeight = model.ChartHeight,
            ShowLegend = model.ShowLegend,
            TickLabelsFontSize = model.TickLabelsFontSize,
            AxisTitlesFontSize = model.AxisTitlesFontSize,
            PlotlyJSON = plotlyJSON
        };

        return Json(chartResults);
```

Here is a screenshot of the query string after the ajax call is done:

[image]

Comment: What does `console.log(result.PlotlyJSON.x)` show?

Comment: Where is that query string showing up?

Comment: That's the browser query string. The browser query string is clean and is just http://myurl/controller/action/id after I load the screen. Then after I click a button which makes the async call you see above, all of these query string values appear on the URL, and it's all the values passed back from the server.

Comment: I suspect Plotly does that so you can save the plot settings.

Comment: I commented out everything that has to do with Plotly and the problem persists. So there is zero Plotly charts on the screen and the async call still appends to the query string.

Comment: It must be something else in your script, jQuery doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: Maybe it's an ASP.NET thing, I don't know anything about that.

Comment: Nah, its not the bad old days of asp.net web forms. This is asp.net core mvc. There is absolutely zero asp.net infrastructure loaded into the browser except an anti-cross site scripting token.

Comment: So if it's not ASP.NET, and `$.ajax()` doesn't do that, it must be something else in your script.

Comment: Look for something that calls `window.history.pushState()`. I think that's the only way to change the query string without reloading the window.

Comment: I don't have anything like that. It's an http put. Is that the issue?

Comment: No, that doesn't make a difference. AJAX doesn't change the query string by itself.

Comment: Issue is that, i did not specify a button type so the browser gave it implicitly assigned the button type as submit. Submitting a form does append the form values on the query string.

Comment: You can also use `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler.

Comment: Yeah good call, which I know about, but the issue here is that I was not aware of the fact that the button was being seen as a submit by default. Thanks for all the responses.

Comment: If you had mentioned that the page was reloading, I might have thought to check that. But there's nothing in the question about a form, or button, or reloading. I thought the query string was changing without reloading.

Comment: So did I! It was too fast.